# object not showing the newly added property after Object.defineProperty() executed

Tags: javascript

```js
var obj = {
  name: "dev",
  age: 27,
}
obj = Object.defineProperty(obj, 'mail', {
  value: 'dev@hmail.com',
  writable: true
});
console.log(obj) // Printing the object with old properties i.e..{  name: 'dev', age: 27 }}
```

With the above code it is showing only the old properties. Why does it not showing the new property "mail" ?

Comment: I run it on FireFox, and there is no problem. Idon know why the snippet is not correct!

Comment: This must have to do with how the console is implemented on StackOverflow. If you execute your code in Chrome or Firefox devtools' console, you see the new property `mail`.

Comment: you can simply do `obj.mail = 'dev@hmail.com'`

Comment: If you add `enumerable: true,` in your call to `Object.defineProperty` it shows.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation for Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) it is said

> By default, values added using Object.defineProperty() are immutable and not **enumerable**.

If you print an object with `console.log(obj)` though, there might be the possibility, that only the enumerable properties are printed (depends on the implementation of console.log). The defined member is still there, but just does not show up.

Printing the member directly works:

```js
var obj = {
    name: "dev",
    age: 27,
};

obj = Object.defineProperty(obj, 'mail', {
    value: 'dev@hmail.com',
    writable:  true
});

console.log(obj.mail);
```

Comment: That's wrong. Run OP's code in Chrome or FF console directly, and you see the mail property.

Comment: @connexo Running the provided code snippet clearly shows the error. This means the problem exists in some places, obviously not in all. I edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is obvious , if you go by the documentation.
[Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

By Default , it sets following default values:

**enumerable: false,
configurable: false,
writable: false,
value: "static",**

so the property you are defining by defineProperty() is immutable , non configurable and most importantly **not enumerable** in your case.

In your code you have given writable as true which does not make it enumerable. The basic use of **defineProperty()** is to provide extra hidden functionalities to your object , they will not be seen unless you force them to.

```js
var obj = {
    name: "dev",
    age: 27,
};

obj = Object.defineProperty(obj, 'mail', {
    value: 'dev@hmail.com',
    writable:  true, //writable will only make it mutuable
});

obj = Object.defineProperty(obj, 'changeMail', {
   set:function(value){
    this.mail = value;
   }
});

console.log(obj.mail) //dev@hmail.com
obj.changeMail = "value@change.com";
console.log(obj.mail) //value@change.com 
console.log(obj); // but the object still remains same
// you can access the property because of the default behavior
```

Now let us understand the **enumerable** parameter

```js
var obj = {
    name: "dev",
    age: 27,
};

obj = Object.defineProperty(obj, 'mail', {
    value: 'dev@hmail.com',
    writable:  true, //writable will only make it mutuable
    enumerable: true //if you wish to show the property simple 
});

console.log("New property is added and can be console logged");
console.log(obj);

//Wait...!!!!

console.log("Not only this now since your enumerable is true , you not only get to see the property but you can perform all the actions like a normal properties");

console.log("Proof that JavaScript is treating the property as normal properties of an object");

console.log(Object.keys(obj)); 

for(let prop in obj){
  console.log(prop);
}
```